# Laravel 5 view not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm having the weirdest error in Laravel 5, and I haven't had this happen in any of my other projects.

**Problem**

I receive the following error when I try to hit my app

No such file or directory (View: /home/vagrant/Code/resources/views/layout/master.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/resources/views/layout/master.blade.php)

However, in my directory structure

[image: it definitely exists!]

And in my blade template

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')
jfoewifjewo[ij
@endsection
```

In my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

Anyone else hit this issue? I've never encountered it before. Yes storage has read/write on both local and homestead.

UPDATE: I'm on Laravel 5.0.13

Comment: if you change the file name and change the extends pointing to the new name, are you getting the same?

Comment: @LeaTano yup, exact same issue

Comment: i think is a well know issue, check this article: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-error-out-of-the-box-with-update-route-throws-an-error and search for "PratyushPundir". He also has the same issue and  other people reported it lter

Comment: However, this was 4 months ago, please try to update Laravel (if this is not the latest one) It might be fixed alredy

Comment: No problem... if you don't mind please accept the answer (if you think this is the answer) Have a nice day.

Comment: By the way, `@endsection` is deprecated since Laravel 4. You should use `@stop` instead.

Comment: That's already been discussed and fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue lies with using Laravel Elixir with homestead. I went back to MAMP to see if I got the same error and what it told me was that I was missing the rev-manifest.json file in public/build. After some digging, I found out that if you don't apply the "versions" function to the elixir function in your gulpfile, the build folder won't be generated and calls to the "elixir" function in your blade templates will fail. This appears to bubble up as an error in finding the view, when it's actually an issue finding a view dependency.

Use gulp to build your sass or less files for sure, but for the time being stick with just URL::asset() to get your javascript and css file paths generated until all the kinks with elixir are worked out.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well know version issue Laravel 5.0.1 (@Zarathuztra version) Here is some comments about the issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-error-out-of-the-box-with-update-route-throws-an-error

Search for "PratyushPundir" and from them you will see some people having the same issue

Updating Laravel should fix it.

Comment: I feel like this answer will definitely help those other than me. Upvote

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by add the version. Because after add the version in gulp, it will generate rev-mainfest.json.

original gulp in homestead

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

I change to

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .version(["public/css/app.css"]);
});
```

And it works.